How to stream text in react-markdown-preview?
I am using @uiw/react-markdown-preview for rendering the text as rich text and working as expected. I need to render the text like streaming, Anyone can help on this?
import MarkdownPreview from '@uiw/react-markdown-preview'; 

const text = "Here's a JavaScript function that generates the Fibonacci sequence up to a given number:\n\n```javascript\nfunction fibonacci(n) {\n  let first = 0;\n  let second = 1;\n\n  console.log(first);\n  console.log(second);\n\n  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {\n    let next = first + second;\n    console.log(next);\n    [first, second] = [second, next];\n  }\n}\n\nfibonacci(10);\n```\n\nThis code will print the Fibonacci sequence up to the 10th number:\n\n0\n1\n1\n2\n3\n5\n8\n13\n21\n34\n\nIf you run this code in a JavaScript environment (like Node.js or a web browser console), it should display these numbers as output."

<MarkdownPreview
   className="mark-down-box"
   source={text}
   wrapperElement={{ "data-color-mode": "dark" }}
/>



I need to render these output like streaming. meaning display the output character by character. Any idea?

To trigger a re-render you need to set it to a state object.
Something like:
const MyComponent = ({value}) => {
   const [content, setContent] = useState("")
   useEffect(() => {
       setContent(value)
   }, [value])
   
   return (
    <MarkdownPreview
   className="mark-down-box"
   source={value}
   wrapperElement={{ "data-color-mode": "dark" }}
    />
    )
}


I don't want to re-render the  text, I need to streaming the text.

What do you mean 'streaming'? If you're talking about receiving something over a http request, we need a lot more detail in your question. If you're just talking about continually updating the text displayed, that's literally what 'render' means.

Actually, I am fetching data from API and passing to the MarkDownPreview library which render the text as rich text which is expected one. But what my requirement is i just need to render the text like typing that i meant by streaming. for example, when you query something to Chatgpt it returns answer like streaming

Regardless, you need to update the state to make literally anything new render. Render is synonymous with 'display something new' in most cases. It's the function that runs to change what's on the screen.
